# Using Ctrl-N,P,F,B arrow keys in Microsoft Word for Mac

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, word-processor

I'd like to use Ctrl-N,P,F,B keys as arrow keys in Word for Mac. I believe this is the system-wide default mapping; it works on browsers, TextEdit, terminal, etc.

The first problem I encountered was that they conflict with Word's built-in keyboard shortcuts. Ctrl-P is "Print", for example.

So I disabled them in `Tools->Customize Keyboard`. For example, under "New Document", I deleted "Ctrl-N". But I think those keys are still being captured by the Word app, instead of the OS. So now nothing happens when I press those keys. The desired behavior is being able to move the cursor.

Comment: Where/how did you define the new definitions for Ctrl-N/P/F/B?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an edit link below it) to add info such as how you're actually trying to set up your keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Thanks, I edited. I can edit again if it's not enough detail. @nohillside I went to `Tools->Customize Keyboard`, found "New Document", and deleted "Ctrl-N". Similar procedure for the rest.

Comment: We understand how you tried to remove the current keybindings in Word. What is unclear is where/how you defined Ctrl-N as "Next line".

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for the response. I did not explicitly define Ctrl-N as "Next Line" (not yet). I was hoping the OS's default mapping would work in the text editing area of the Word app. But maybe it's implemented differently and doesn't work like native text boxes. If that's the case, I think the problem gets complicated. How would you go about this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: AFAIK the default bindings only work if applications rely on Cocoa functionality, it won't work out of the box for Word documents (it *does* work in dialog boxes opened within Word already as these are usually Cocoa-based.

Comment: I see. Initially I thought maybe its simple and someone's done it before. But it seems more trouble than its worth. Thanks for taking time to ask and explain.

Comment: Also try the Word for Mac forum if you haven't already.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac